# Adding 'Move To' to windows file context menu

Tags: windows

Something like 'Send to' (but it copies or creates shortcuts), I'd like to move (cut and paste) files to custom locations by just right clicking file > 'move to' > list of select few folders.

Is there any way of doing this in windows xp (and 7)? preferably some script and/or regedit tweak instead of some bloated software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now how much things have changed on Win7, as I'm on ubuntu now.
But in WinXP, whathever you put in the folder:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Some User Name\SendTo

Becomes an item in the right-click context menu, under the option 'send to'.

Thus you can put a batch file in it, named, for example, as "My documents (moving)".
So, open notepad and put this as content:

```
move %1 "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents"
```

And save it as "My documents (moving).bat" - take care to select "files of type > all files" so the file extension wont be renamed to ".bat.txt"

That's it, you can adapt to your needs and make a link to the batch file instead of putting it directly under the 'send to' folder in order to change the name and icon at will.